# how to use loc in dataframe to get all values of columns except last one in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe in python. I am trying to get values from a particular row by using slicing. It works well when I try with all (:) or by using start index to end(start_index:). But it does not work when I use it with negative indexing to select upto last value(:-1).

Consider the following:

```
a=df.loc[:,'mid'] 
print(len(a))
17279

a=df.loc[1:,'mid'] 
print(len(a))
17278

a=df.loc[:-1,'mid'] 
print(len(a))
0
```

I should get length of a as 17278 in the third example, But I get no output for it. Please let me know how to properly get all values of column in dataframe except last one using -ve indexing.

Negative indexing works fine when using with lists

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(a[:-1])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions, but need also position of column `mid` by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
a=df.iloc[:-1,df.columns.get_loc('mid')]
```

Or slicing `df.index`:

```
a=df.loc[df.index[:-1],'mid']
```